# How can I prevent the comments section in my WordPress site from spanning the full screen?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have recently set up my wordpress site, but the comments section below each post spans the full width of the screen, rather than following the margins used in the rest of the page. How do I set the margins to be the same as the rest of the page for this section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your footer elements need to be within the `container` ID div tag. Or they must be wrapped in their own div with an ID or class given the style

```
#footerWrapper {
width: 768px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will center and align them to the main container div. It's most likely the wordpress functions were moved around in the template files.

The footer on your home page you'll see is wrapped in

`<div id="footer" class="full left"></div>`

So someone messed up your single.php template file. That's it because your index, pages, archives are all ok so whatever template most likely single.php needs to be edited.

Comment: @RichAshworth you're welcome if you need any other help leave a comment.